# Formatting databar object

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA script that adds in a `databar` conditional formatting for a range.  I have written the code below, however, I don't know how to change the color of the `databar`, and provide different bounds on it.

Oddly enough, when I set the `minpoint` to 0, it works, but I am unable to set the `maxpoint` to a named variable (set to type `integer`).  Where am I going wrong?

```
Set bar = rangeTest.FormatConditions.AddDatabar

'assign max value + 1 for databar upper bound
maxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rangeTest) + 1

With bar
    .BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
    .BarColor = RGB(189, 215, 238) 'error thrown here (Object doesn't support this property)
End With

With rangeTest.FormatConditions(1)
    .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=0  'xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
    .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax 'error thrown here (invalid procedure call)
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use:

- `Color` property of `FormatColor` object returned by `BarColor` property
- `xlConditionValueNumber` and `newvalue` arguments of `Modify()` method of the `ConditionValue` object returned by `MaxPoint` property

so your code would be:

```
With bar
    .BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
    .BarColor.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238) 
End With

With rangeTest.FormatConditions(1)
    .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=0  'xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
    .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=maxValue       
End With
```